# Stuck in database structuring

Tags: mysql, database

I need a small help in making a mysql database structure

I am making a site where I ll be having users and cartoon characters as two major entities

A user can like as many cartoon character, and a cartoon character can be liked by n number of users.

My doubt is, in the users table there will be a field named as Cartoon, this will hold a single cartoon character ID, but if the user likes many characters then how do I store it?

This is my first database structure, so please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach is to use separate relation table, i.e.

```
create table users_cartoons (user_id int, cartoon_id int)
```

and store all the relations between users and cartoons there.

Comment: but this will make the table really heavy, like if a userA liked Mickey, userB liked Donald and userC liked Mickey then this way Mickey or any other character will be repeated and will make a long list.

Will this be a good way?

Comment: @Nick: Quite contrary, this is the lightest structure possible in terms of used space. Yes, characters will be repeated - but in your structure they will _inevitably_ be repeated and separate table is the lightest way to store such relations - just make sure you're storing IDs (unique integer values), not names for both users and characters.

Comment: Ok, just tell me what will be the best solution amongst this:-

A database with 1000+ tables of cartoon character

OR

A database with 10 tables but one table with a long list of duplication of rows.

Comment: Of course one large table will be better. Databases are designed to store large amounts of data in relatively simple structure - the more complex your database model is the worse performance and more complex queries you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

You need three tables: a Users table, a Cartoons table, and a UsersCartoons table.

Users has all your users (id, user names, etc). Cartoons has all the cartoons (an id for each one, and whatever other properties you want to store).

Then the UsersCartoons table has a user_id field and a cartoon_id field. You can add as many rows as you want to that table, so each cartoon can be liked by n users and vice-versa.

Comment: @Nick, I don't have the reputation to comment on your thread below with Sergey but, to answer your question, one relationship table (like UserCartoons) will be faster than a separate table for each cartoon for a couple of reasons.

First, what if you want to get every cartoon liked by a User? If each cartoon has it's own table, you have to join together the results of many tables, which is very slow.

Second, MySQL can make indexes behind the scenes that don't include the duplicates so it won't be searching through every row each time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of the structure I would likely use.

I find it better to maintain a database of tables that describes the data in it, rather than something like `user_cartoon`, which is often a very vague representation.

```
`user`
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

`cartoon_character`
user_id denotes the creator or owner
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

`cartoon_character_like`
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cartoon_character_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id              | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```